# How can explain the effect of the added exogenous variable on the model looking at graph?

Tags: regression, time-series, arima

I have run the ARIMAX model (1,1,1) and got this output. 
[image]

Then I ran SARIMAX (1,1,1) Seasonal (1,1,52) model and got the next
[image]

As you see the blue line (Prediction) came closer to the black line (Real values).

How can I explain, in a fancy way, that adding the seasonality factor has filled the gap between the real values and predicted values?

Comment: Why do you want to explain it in "a fancy way"? Also, I would be EXTREMELY wary of using a seasonal model with less than two full years of data at the very least, and you seem to have only 9 months.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thank you for your answer.  Because I need to provide a professional answer. I can't say that the seasonal factor has brough the brediction line closer to the real values line. 
It's a test set. On train set I have 2 years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write something like:

> The seasonal ARIMA model improves on the non-seasonal one by reducing the Mean Squared Error on the test set from $x$ to $y$. In addition, the visible fit is better, too.

That would be quite enough for me as a reviewer.

Comment: love it! Thank you so much